# Print Control-m runtime variable

Tags: variables, output, jobs, job-scheduling, control-m

I'm creating a Web Services Control-M job in while I'm populating a few a few variables at run time based on %%OMONNAM, %%RMONNAM, %%MONNAM and other parameters.
I want to view/print these variables in output/sysout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple echo would do that:

```
echo %%OMONNAM
echo %%RMONNAM
echo %%MONNAM
```